# Return yesterday's date in shell script using awk or echo

Tags: shell, date, time

I am sure there is a simple answer to this :

Why does the following not give me the date and time in a script? What should I use rather than awk? Awk works fine if I need to query files but I guess it is the wrong thing to use here..

Code :

```
$ySTD=$(date --date yesterday "+%Y-%m-%d")  | awk '{print substr($1,1,10)}'

echo ${ySTD}
echo 'STD calculated from DATE - last 24 hrs data will be fetched'

${ySTM}=$(date --date yesterday "+%T")|  awk  '{print substr($1,1,5)}' 
echo ${ySTM}
```

In the shell I get this when the script runs:

```
+ awk '{print substr($1,1,10)}'
++ date --date yesterday +%Y-%m-%d
+ =2014-07-03
logdat3: line 41: =2014-07-03: command not found
+ echo

+ echo 'STD calculated from DATE - last 24 hrs data will be fetched'
STD calculated from DATE - last 24 hrs data will be fetched
+ awk '{print substr($1,1,5)}'
++ date --date yesterday +%T
+ =11:33:34
logdat3: line 45: =11:33:34: command not found
+ echo
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: When setting variables in the shell, don't prefix with `$` or use parameter expansion brackets `${...}`.  That is only for referencing values assigned to variables.  Also, when using command substitution, the closing parenthesis must enclose all the commands with which you want the output, including pipes, e.g. `ySTM=$(date --date yesterday "+%T"|  awk  '{print substr($1,1,5)}')`

Comment: @user3778424 please mark que answer as solver.

Answer (score 1):

You're rigth, no  awk  needed:

```
$ read ySTD ySTM < <(date --date yesterday "+%Y-%m-%d %T")                                                                     
$ echo $ySTD
2014-07-03
$ echo $ySTM
12:16:37
```

Anyway , your original code fixed:

```
ySTD=$(date --date yesterday "+%Y-%m-%d")

echo ${ySTD}
echo 'STD calculated from DATE - last 24 hrs data will be fetched'

ySTM=$(date --date yesterday "+%T") 
echo ${ySTM}
```

You don't need to get a substring.